# Cannot create a company page without picking benefits; Icons need text descriptions

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I can't complete my Careers company page because I have not selected any benefits.

Apart from the fact that I can't seem to get any of the icons to actually select (I'm using Chrome). The main problem is that I don't know what any of the icons mean and there is no explanation in that older, perhaps less cool, designer symbology known as written English.

I have guessed the first few, the umbrella means leaky flat roofed office block, the baby in diapers means infantile management and the cross means Swiss army knife required to build your own PC - but I don't get the others.

Comment: Diapers == Long coding sessions ahead, bring Depend; Cross == We regularly donate to Red Cross blood drives; Umbrella-ella-ella == Vacations to London; $ == Expect payment for your work

Comment: How rude @random! It's been 25 Celsius and sunny for a few weeks in London (just not today...)

Comment: I just tested the icons and I didn't have an issue with Chrome 35 on OSX 10.9. Can you post a screenshot of the developer console?

Comment: @juice - I think I got it, you have to enter some text where it says "add benefit"

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have to add text where it says "add benefit" which looks and responds like a button.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of what the icons mean.  They're not meant to be constraining since we can't anticipate all benefits offered by companies, but we tried to pick some art work that could be used for often offered benefits like sick leave policies, health care, compensation, workplace environment etc...  Some like the smiley face or star are pretty versitile.  I included how we use some of the icons on [our page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange) but it's really up to you.

[image: Benefits example]

We could be more clear about the need to include the text with the icon by re-wording the helper text.  We'll do that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense